# Npm start/install doesn't work: Npm can't find the file

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, truffle, npm-start

I download the react box from truffle and wanted to use npm install and start but both don't work. I looked other post that said:

1. set the path `"%SystemRoot%\system32"`,open cmd in admin then use npm start
2. npm config set ignore-scripts false
3. Confirming that I'm well in the directory containing `package.json`

Here is what looks like the downloaded box (I used to run npm start and install in both of these directory):

[image]
[image]

And here is the errors log that I have with npm start in both the SupChainBasicVersion folder and client folder:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Heraxia\SupChainBasicVersion\package.json'
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Heraxia\SupChainBasicVersion
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
7 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v12.18.3
9 verbose npm  v6.14.6
10 error code ENOENT
11 error syscall open
12 error path C:\Users\Heraxia\SupChainBasicVersion\package.json
13 error errno -4058
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Heraxia\SupChainBasicVersion\package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

[image]

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~prestart: client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: client@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Local\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Heraxia\SupChainBasicVersion\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Local\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Local\VSCode\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8\bin;C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Heraxia\SupChainBasicVersion\client
10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Local\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Local\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Heraxia\SupChainBasicVersion\client
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Heraxia\\AppData\\Local\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

[image]

Please help me, I thinks that I will go crazy with these errors. I already worked on it for over 2 hours and I don't know what to do.

I thank anybody who will take the time to try to help me.

Comment: it looks you run `npm install` in where not containing package.json. i think you have to do it inside `client` folder

Comment: @yash I did it both inside the SupChainBasicVersion and the client folder, but always the same error

Comment: Ciao, where did you download these files from? Can you show me the link?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito From here https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/react

Comment: @Tameiki if I see something like "Good to Go! Your Truffle Box is installed and ready." on my localhost:3000, this means that I solved your problem? Sorry, I have never used truffle box...

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Normally yes you solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

`package.json` file is located inside your `client` directory.

Go to `client` folder and remove both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

Make sure that you have `"react-scripts": "xxx"` in your `package.json`.

> If you don't have, `npm install --save react-scripts`

Run `npm install` again and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Tried but still doesn't work, I have an error log with near 8k lines :'(

Comment: I can't post it here or on a pastebin, so here a google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gYDG_spWQJ7Z_diyrP_-HT9TS8GDX2kL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i saw your errors, i can see that it is because of outdated packages in your package.json.

Comment: yes, your node js version is above 12 and some of your packages needs node version under 8.

Comment: Ok thanks I will see on the net how to automatically update them

Comment: you can use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates`

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to follow this steps:

1. install truffle: open PowerShell in administrative mode and go into `C:\Users\<yourusername>` and run `npm install -g truffle`;
2. create a folder (make sure is empty), then open a command prompt in administrative mode, navigate into new folder and run `npx truffle unbox react`;
3. when download is finished, on the same command prompt run `truffle develop`. This command opens the truffle development console;
4. on the development console run `compile`;
5. then run `migrate`;
6. keep open the development console, open another command prompt in administrative mode and navigate into the new folder you created before;
7. run `cd client`;
8. run `npm run start`;

The result will be:

[image]

As you can see I changed the value stored on line 40 in App.js from 5 to 6.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work for me. At step two I have: https://pastebin.com/4WqJDKgp

Comment: Ciao, we have basically the same truffle and node version (for node I have 12.16.2, you 12.18.3 and I don't think this is the problem). I serched your error in internet but the only problems I found are connection problems (e.g. china firewall), never a missing directory problem. The only thing I could say is that maybe the command does not have administrative rights to create a folder (but you launched command prompt in administrative mode). Sounds really weird. Let me try to reproduce your error. I will answer you as soon as possible.

Comment: Sorry let me ask you a quesition: can you check if you have `C:\Users\Heraxia\AppData\Local\Temp\` folder?

Comment: Yes I have it and inside there is two empty npm folder.
Edit: Wait now it's downloading, I will give you a return when I finish to do all steps

Comment: Ok so maybe you are pointing to a wrong folder. Go in Enviroment variables and check if  `TMP` and `TEMP` are setted to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`. If no, set them and retry to run `npx truffle unbox react`.

Comment: Euh I had your screen for a few seconds before I got that: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V0N3RpTVQzRAIePed1It1QFXpVgbNyv1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you run `compile` and `migrate` before run `npm run start` ? Remember, run `npm run start` from another command prompt by keeping truffle development console up and running.

Comment: I run compile and migrate on the cmd where I runned truffle develop. And I opened a new cmd where I launched npm run start